# Is there a true successor alternative to svanoort/pyresttest?

Tags: software-testing, rest

`pyresttest` follows a very useful concept:

- you install it (or put it in a docker container),
- you write a simple `yaml` containing your tests and finally
- run it in your ci/build-pipeline against your API directly

Above all, it is free.

Sadly, the repo is not being maintained anymore and there is no direct or clear successor or alternative.

Is there any free API/Rest test software that supports:

- test definition via single file (e.g. `yaml`)
- parsing responses (json) into variables to use for use in other requests
- focused on CLI interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Tavern](https://taverntesting.github.io/)

From the documentation :

Automated RESTful API testing

A **command-line tool** and Python library and Pytest plugin for automated testing of **RESTful APIs, with a simple, concise and flexible YAML-based syntax**

Why not Postman, Insomnia or **pyresttest** etc?

Tavern is a focused tool which does one thing well: automated testing of APIs.

**pyresttest** is a similar tool to Tavern for testing RESTful APIs, but is no longer actively developed. On top of MQTT testing, Tavern has several other advantages over PyRestTest which overall add up to a better developer experience:

```
Cleaner test syntax which is more intuitive, especially for non-developers
Validation function are more flexible and easier to use
Better explanations of why a test failed
```